# Socket.io 1.3.5 protocol and Jmeter benchmarking

Tags: socket.io, jmeter, benchmarking, stress-testing, jmeter-plugins

I'm trying to benchmark socket.io 1.3.5 with Jmeter and the following websocket plugin (https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler).

When implementing the socket.io protocol in Jmeter to emulate the same connection steps I see in google dev tools I'm having a 20s delay between some frames. Please, can you give me some advice to get this working properly and remove this delay? Thank you!!

In Jmeter:

1. HTTP REQUEST [GET] socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=${timestamp} HTTP
2. HTTP REQUEST [GET] socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=${timestamp}&sid=${sessionid} HTTP
3. WEBSOCKET REQUEST socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&t=${timestamp}&sid=${sessionid} WS
   REQUEST DATA: 2probe
4. WEBSOCKET REQUEST socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=${sessionid}
   REQUEST DATA: 5
5. WEBSOCKET REQUEST socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=${sessionid}
   REQUEST DATA: 42["auth", "test", "test", "test"]

In Node socket.io debug:
screenshot -> http://postimg.org/image/5p08vszv3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't continue to ping the server, ping timeout occurs and connection changes to xhr-polling, not socket connection any more. That's why it takes 20 seconds.